# java.lang.ArithmeticException: Negative exponent in jruby

Tags: java, jruby

I have the following JRuby code :

```
def knuth(a, n, b)
   if n ==1
      r = a**b
   else
      r = 1
      b.times do
         r = knuth a, n-1, r
      end
   end
   return r
end
k = knuth 3, 4, 5
puts k
puts k.size
```

But it give me

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: Negative exponent

any idea why ?

I'm on Windows and using jruby-9.0.0.0.pre2-p0

Comment: Looks like the only place where you can get a `NegativeExponent` is `a**b`, so you can add `puts b` to your `if n ==1` branch and see what`s going on.

Comment: its give me1
1
1
3
27
1
3
27
7625597484987
Infinity
Infinity

Comment: it does not seem to finish in a reasonable time on MRI 1.9.3/2.2 and prints us a warning: `pow_failure.rb:3: warning: in a**b, b may be too big` ... so it's probably unspecified teritory whether this should work (as noted in the answer bellow with 'big' integers passed to `pow`)

Comment: put this in an issue at https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/3037

Answer (score 1):

There are two things at work here. First, in the JVM all numbers are signed. Thus, when `r` grows large enough that the high-order bit gets set the number actually becomes negative, hence the error. The second thing is that each time you go through the `b.times` loop `r` is being reassigned such that during the next iteration the value of `r` being passed to `knuth` is much larger, causing the new value for `r` to again be greatly increased and so on until `r` becomes negative.

Comment: Jruby does not convert r into bignum?
And then r is still lose sign bit?

Comment: @Creends `bignum` is a Ruby class, so internally the JVM needs some other way to represent values of that class. JRuby uses `RubyBignum` which stores the value in a `BigInteger` (hence no sign bit), but when doing `a**b` it casts `b` to Java's primitive `int` (because `BigInteger.pow` only takes an `int` argument) and that's when the number becomes negative.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know that. So there is no way to have a BigInteger exponent ?

Comment: @Creends Sadly, yes. The closest thing is `modPow(BigInteger, BigInteger)` which raises a number to a power but only with the a modulus (like doing `(x ** y) % z`). The result for JRuby, then, is that it has different behavior than c ruby for sufficiently large exponents.